# Как чередовать символы в строке? JS

Tags: javascript, строки

С помощью цикла сформируйте строку -1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9- и запишите ее в переменную str. Выведите значение этой переменной на экран.

Я пишу так:

```
let str2 = '';

for (let v = 1; v <= 9; v++) {

    str2 = str2 + v;

}

console.log(str2);
```

Это выведет цифры, а как вывести дефисы я не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а если так?

```
let str2 = "-";

for (let v = 1; v <= 9; v++) {

    str2 = str2 + v + "-";
}

console.log(str2);
```

Comment: только дефис спереди, а, не увидел что там и так и так :)

Comment: @Grundy, почему - первый дефис стоит в строке, а потом нужны только дефисы сзади

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = '';
for (let i = 1, k='-'; i <= 9; i++, k='-') {
    str =  str + k + i;
}
console.log(str + '-');
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Зачем нужно переприсваивать `k` в цикле, если это константный литерал?

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = ''

for (let i = 1; i <= 19; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        str += '-'
    } else {
        str += i/2
    }
}

console.log(str);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: как-то излишне сложновато :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = '';

for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    str += '-';
     if(i != 10){
      str += i;
  }
}
console.log(str)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]